# Error while running ng serve command in Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have recently created a project using angular-cli and am unable to run it using ng serve

while running ng serve command it throws this error

> Cannot read property 'AssetUrl' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'AssetUrl' of undefined
>      at Object. (/Users/shaan/Sites/node-apps/migration/Outgrow-frontend/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/private_import_compiler.js:10:51)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider taking following steps:

1. check your angular-cli.json and package.json for version of angular-cli in your project, it should be same e.g. ("version": "1.0.0-beta.x").
2. install angular-cli as global package using

   npm install -g angular-cli

this should fix your problem.

Comment: where is angular-cli.json?

Comment: @CoryDorning it will be created when you initialize your project by using ng new <poject-name> and ng init

Comment: okay gotcha. my issue is that I'm getting the AssetUrl error when trying to initialize a new project. :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue by updating angular-cli to v1.0.0-beta.18 (which is latest build) and did "ng init" within local project folder.

follow https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli